# Apply function to object filled with numbers

Tags: javascript

I have this simple function that adds a certain number of days to a given date and gets the new date:

```
var adddays = 401;
var theDate = new Date(2014, 01, 01);
var myNewDate = new Date(theDate);
myNewDate.setDate(myNewDate.getDate() + adddays);
console.log(myNewDate);
```

Rather than doing one date at a time, I'm now getting dates in an object like this: `{543,563,601,629,650,672,698,718}`

The question is how I can run all these days through this function to get an object with newly formatted dates. These numbers in the object would substitute for `adddays`. I know I need a for loop, but I'm a little new to JS to figure it out.

Comment: Object or array? Also, there are many JavaScript tutorials, that can teach you about loops, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration .

Comment: I assume you're using an array, not an object: `[543,563,601,629,650,672,698,718]`

Comment: @Andy For whatever reason, what's stored in the database is this format `{543,563,601,629,650,672,698,718}`

Comment: So, is that a string?

Comment: @FelixKling I suppose it is. Hadn't looked at it like that. Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var theDate = new Date(2014, 01, 01);
var newDates = ([543,563,601,629,650,672,698,718]).map(function (e) {
  var adddays = e;
  var myNewDate = new Date(theDate);
  myNewDate.setDate(myNewDate.getDate() + adddays);
  console.log(myNewDate);
  return myNewDate;
})
```

or

```
var str = "{543,563,601,629,650,672,698,718}";
var theDate = new Date(2014, 01, 01);
var newDates = (str.substr(1,str.length-1).split(',')).map(function (e) {
  var adddays = parseInt(e,10);
  var myNewDate = new Date(theDate);
  myNewDate.setDate(myNewDate.getDate() + adddays);
  console.log(myNewDate);
  return myNewDate;
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to assign the result to a var `var newDates = ([543...]).map..`

Comment: Thanks. The first option runs fine, but the second is more of what I need, but I'm getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: ParseInt is not defined"

Comment: Changed from ParseInt to parseInt and worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Try to include the radix when you work with `parseInt(e, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

The string you are receiving is not a valid javascript Object and looks more like an array. We will first have to transform it from a string to an array.

```
var daysToAdd = "{543,563,601,629,650,672,698,718}";
//Removing the {} brackets to turn it into a CSV
daysToAdd = daysToAdd.substring(1,daysToAdd.length-1)
//Using split to turn our values into an array
daysToAdd = daysToAdd.split(',');
//daysToAdd now looks like ["543","563","601","629","650","672","698","718"]
```

We will want to make a function that accepts the base data and returns the adjusted dates for re-usability. In our function we can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to call a function on each element in our array

```
function addAllDaysToDate(daysToAdd,referenceDate){
    var adjustedDays = daysToAdd.map(function(addDays){
         var date = new Date();
         //+variable is shorthand for parseInt(variable);
         date.setDate(referenceDate.getDate() + (+addDays));
         return date;
    });
    //Our adjustedDays is now an array of Date objects 
    return adjustedDays;
}
```

We can then use our function to get the adjusted dates

```
var theDate = new Date(2014, 01, 01);
var myNewDates = addAllDaysToDate(daysToAdd,theDate)
```

Comment: `daysToAdd.substring(1,daysToAdd.length-1)` is wrong.  It should be `daysToAdd.substring(1,daysToAdd.length-2)`.